# PHP task terminated but no error condition raised

Tags: php, error-handling, timeout

A PHP script is using the ZipArchive class and is potentially long running.
Since it is dying silently but writing a partial zip file, I wrapped error_log() statements around the $zip->close().  (ini_set sets error logging to a file and E_ALL just before this code)
    error_log("calling zip->close()");
    $rc = $zip->close();
    error_log("zip->close() returned $rc");

The logging file shows the first error_log, but never the second.
A unix top command shows the process running for a total CPU time of c. 2.5 minutes before it goes defunct.

I have also tried trapping the error with set_error_handler(), and the handler using error_log() to record the catch.  But nothing shows up in the log file.

I'm assuming the process is being bounced, maybe by Apache (I have no control over Apache or PHP).

My question is:  why can't I see this error in the file being used by error_log?

Thanks for the suggestions for circumventing the problem, but my question remains:

**Why can't I see this error in the log?  Or why can't I catch this error via set_error_handler()?**

Comment: Maybe max execution time exceeded?

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php to control how much time is allowed to your script

Comment: I know your question is ACUTALLY about why the error isn't showing up, but try the set time limit thing

Answer (score 1):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

0 = Indefinitely

Comment: Also note, while apache might cut the request off, php will still run